# CSS change image color between two values

Tags: php, css

I've been trying to change the color of an image regarding to a variable, but I can't figure it out.
"-hue rotate" seems to be a tough fit for what I'm searching.

For now I've hardcoded some values within php, css-selectors shown at the example below, but since the hue-rotate degrees seem to be all over the place, how am I able to produce a color which lays between the current hardcoded ones?

Gradient for Example:

[image]

```
>= 27 = hot (red)
>= 24 = semi-hot (orange-ish)
>= 22.5 = middle (yellow)
>= 20 = ok (green)
>= 18 = semi-cold (turqoise)
>= 7 = cold (blue)
<7 = ice (lightblue)
```

code:

```
.temp-ice{
-webkit-filter: brightness(172%) grayscale(84%) hue-rotate(260deg);
filter: brightness(172%) grayscale(84%) hue-rotate(260deg);

}
.temp-cold{
-webkit-filter: brightness(100%) hue-rotate(260deg);
filter: brightness(100%) hue-rotate(260deg);
}

.temp-semi-cold{
-webkit-filter: brightness(120%) hue-rotate(245deg);
filter: brightness(120%) hue-rotate(245deg);
}

.temp-ok{
-webkit-filter: brightness(110%) hue-rotate(170deg);
filter: brightness(110%) hue-rotate(170deg);
}

.temp-middle{
-webkit-filter: brightness(120%) hue-rotate(130deg);
filter: brightness(120%) hue-rotate(130deg);
}

.temp-semi-hot{
-webkit-filter: brightness(90%) hue-rotate(115deg);
filter: brightness(90%) hue-rotate(115deg);
}

.temp-hot{
-webkit-filter: brightness(60%) hue-rotate(60deg);
filter: brightness(60%) hue-rotate(60deg);
}
```

(ignore the brightness, it's just to fix the imagebrightness)
How it currently looks like:

[image]